# iOS silent push not work when APP in background

Tags: swift, apple-push-notifications, ios10

I used JPush to post a silent_push.

I can not recived silent push when APP in background.

The AppDelegate's method

```
application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler
```

not fire.

But It was working in foreground.

Background Modes:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2NEA.png)

Where I missing?

// plist

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrz7q.png)

**NEW UPDATW :**

I closed my idevice's background refresh feature....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you added this in your `plist`

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>fetch</string>
</array>
```

Comment: Yes, but you need to add these keys in `plist` also.